# Laravel 5.2 token mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, token, csrf

I'm updating a Laravel 5.1 site to Laravel 5.2.39. I had a lot of issues with the "approved" upgrade process (in particular the middleware) so I ended up creating a new Laravel 5.2 site and just moving over my views, models and controllers from the old site. It seems to be working, except when I submit any form I get a token mismatch exception:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

My forms have the token (using `{{ csrf_field() }}`) in them:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['placeholder' => 'Name', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}
    {!! Form::email('email', old('email'), ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone') !!}
    {!! Form::text('phone', old('phone'), ['placeholder' => 'Phone', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-small']) !!}
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" />
</div>
```

and I have cleared my cookies and also tried setting the `config/session.php` `lifetime` to a higher number to ensure it's not timing out.

This is running on a homestead box.

Any ideas what to try?

EDIT: here's the route in question

```
Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController');
```

EDIT2: here's the route file. I don't believe it is required to wrap the routes in the web middleware in Laravel 5.2-- however, I've tried it both ways with the same error.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'AccountController@index');

    Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');
    Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController');

});
```

Dumping the `$request->session()->token()` in the controller's create action shows the current session token on the page with the form. This is the same token that is added to the form (checked with view source).

But when it gets to the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::tokensMatch()` class, I dump the session token and it's different than the form token-- meaning these will never match. Not sure what to expect here.

Comment: Can you please show your ```POST``` route for that forum?

Comment: @xdevnull-- it's on a `resource` route but I'll edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: @user101278 Are they under Web Group Middleware?

Comment: @xdevnull-- no, there's just 4 resource routes at the moment and none are in a group and none have middleware explicitly attached. I thought in `5.2` the web middleware is automatically applied?

Comment: Version > ```5.2.28```

Comment: The csrf_field should be used with {!! csrf_field() !!}.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy-- the laravel docs say use `{{ csrf_field() }}`-- however, I tried the other way and it is still throwing the error

Comment: can you share your route file?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim-- route file added above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really annoying, but after everything else it appears this was a weird error caused by multiple Laravel sites on one Homestead box. I had set the session key differently and had cleared caches, but it still wasn't working.

Destroying the homestead box and rebuilding it appears to have fixed this issue. Thanks for all the comments and attempts at finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have your `Form:open` declaration, you no longer need the separate **csrf_field** line. `Form::open` should take care of it.

Are you using the laravel collective form package? The old illuminate package is no longer maintained.

As the previous user said, all routes also must be wrapped in the web middleware group, which also could be the problem.

Comment: Yes, this is the laravel collective package.

Comment: The form example above does not show the form open and close declarations. Was it just left out of your example code or missing?

Comment: yes, that's just a partial. The form is working fine, and I can verify that the token payload is getting to the controller's `store` action if I disable the token check in the middleware

Answer (score 0):

Place your route within web Middleware. or in `App\http\kernel` copy all routes from web to protected `$middleware` array.